# Click (), send Keys () functions are not available for find element by x path option

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python version 3.8.2 with selenium 3.14.1.

I am new to both Python and Selenium. I am using Pycharm to write my automation scripts.

When i try to use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath().click()` command, The click() option is not displayed in the drop down.

The same `click()` option is available if i use `driver.find_element_by_name or driver.find_element_by_id` commands.

Find elements by Name

[image]

Find elements by id

[image]

How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Your first link is to an image in your own pc

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

> **To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):**
>
> - *find_elements_by_name*
> - *find_elements_by_xpath*
> - ...

You can't call `.click` on `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` because `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` returns a list of elements, rather than a single element.

Suppose `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()` returns 10 elements.  What do you want to do with these 10 elements?  Click on the first one?  Click on the last one?  Click on all of them?

If you only want to find a single element using XPath, use `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` (note, no `s` after `element`) instead.

The documentation page I linked to above lists 8 methods for finding a single element on the page.  All of these methods apart from `find_element_by_id` have a corresponding method for returning multiple elements, whose name differs only by replacing `element` with `elements`.  (There is no `find_elements_by_id` method because `id`s are supposed to be unique: there should never be more than one element with the same `id`.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding for above answer.
You can use a List to store webelements and loop through them while doing actions. Something in java.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("001"));
for(WebElement ele:elements) {
                ele.click();
}
```